# Modificar ruta de Redmine (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una instalación de Redmine montada y funcionando, a la cual puedo acceder directamente escribiendo la ip de la máquina virtual o `http://nombredemimaquinavirtual` (en un servidor aparte) en la barra de navegación del explorador. Pero cuando quiero entrar desde una dirección externa no carga el css y las rutas están mal, además necesito que pasen por un proxy que tengo de tal forma que la aplicación sepa de donde viene la peticion, lo explico:

Yo quiero acceder a mi Redmine desde esta dirección a la máquina virtual

```
http://nombrecompañia/miservidor/nombredemimaquinavirtual/
```

Y accedo, pero como ya he dicho el css no carga y las rutas de los enlaces está mal, porque no tienen la parte de

> `/miservidor/nombredemimaquinavirtual/`

por ejemplo:

```
http://nombrecompañia/login
```

Necesito cambiarlo

```
http://nombrecompañia/miservidor/nombredemimaquinavirtual/login
```

¿cómo lo cambio? entiendo que tendré que modificar la url relativa, pero no sé donde.

Entorno de trabajo:

Apache2.

Rails 3.2.22 (no puedo actualizarlo)

ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux] (tampoco puedo actualizarlo)

ruby-on-rails redmine

Muchas gracias por el tiempo de leerme, un saludo.

Comment: No se si te sirva [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675193/how-can-i-globally-override-a-rails-url-helper). Podrías condicionarlo para que el path agregue `miservidor/nombredemimaquinavirtual` solo cuando corra en production o el entorno donde esté funcionando tu aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, efectivamente, creo que agregar loq ue necesito al path cuando corra en production sería mi solución, el caso es que no encuentro dónde deberia cambiarlo. 
Gracias al link qu eme has proporcionado he conseguido cambiar la url, pero no consigo que esté en el orden correcto, se queda algo así como 
`http://nombrecompañia/login/miservidor/nombredemimaquinavirtual` el tema es que "login" no sé lo que es, y no lo puedo modificar si no sé lo que es.